# A problem in arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

Okay, so I recently began learning the number system, i.e., the place value system, viz., the decimal system. I understand how the 1st place from the right represents the number of ones, the second place from the right represents the number of groups of ten and so on. But then I came across this question:

```
                           *What is 3 tens and 14 ones?*
```

**My question is, what exactly does it mean to say 14 ones?**

According to the place value system, $1$ represents the number of groups of ten and $4$ represent the number of ungrouped ones. I can think of fourteen straight lines like such: |||||||||||||| - but notice how I said 'fourteen' and not $14$ because doesn't '$14$' mean - [||||||||||]||||

Comment: Sorry, I made an error..

Comment: Anyway, what is the answer to that particular question you have a doubt about ?

Comment: @Spectre The answer is 44

Comment: Then they have asked it like this : $30 + 14$ = ?

Comment: they asked what 3 tens ($\implies 3 \times 10 = 30$) and 14 ones ($\implies 14 \times 1 = 14$) is, so basically you have to add both.

Comment: The notation $14$ arguably implies an organization of the fourteen ones into a group of ten with four left over, but that organization is independent of the number being represented: the representations ‘$14$ ones’ and ‘fourteen ones’ denote exactly the same number. And ‘$3$ tens and $14$ ones’ denotes the same number as ‘$30+14$’, ‘two score and four’, ‘forty-four ones’, and ‘$44$’.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for filling up the gap I left :)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I would highly appreciate it if you could elaborate upon your answer more.

Comment: @SathvikR.: I honestly don’t know what more I could say. There are infinitely many notations that can be used to denote a given real number. Different notations may suggest different ways of thinking about the number, but it’s still the same number.

Comment: @SathvikR. to make it more clear, you were asked another representation 44 and to get that number from the given representation. The words "3 tens and 14 ones' were just a clue to what the number is. In fact, it is more like describing an animal without knowing what the animal's name is.